# Do I delete memories inside a function's scope?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Question 1: How do I delete res from memory without corrupting the return?

```
Class1 *GetType(Class1 type)
{
    Class1 *res = nullptr;
    switch (type)
    {
        case SCRIPTS_SPELL:
        {
            res = &sSpellScripts;
            break;
        }
        case SCRIPTS_EVENT:
        {
            res = &sEventScripts;
            break;
        }
        case SCRIPTS_POINT:
        {
            res = &sWaypointScripts;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Question 2: Do I delete clicker and click from memory inside the function or not?

```
bool Class2::IsFitToRequirements(Unit const *clicker, Unit const *click) const
```

Question 3: Do I delete memories that have a pointer or not? Example:

```
QueryResult result = Database.Query(some query);
if (!result)
{
    delete &result; // Should I or not?
    return;
}
```

Comment: ................ what?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 2 is something we can not answer, because we lack information.

About question 1, you can not delete the object, because if you do, then what you return is deleted.

As a matter of fact, `res` will go out of scope as soon as the function terminates.

Question 3: No you don't since it's already NULL.

Comment: I know! :-(

That's what I thought too. :/

Btw, I updated another question, if someone (or you) can answer it, I will be in great depth. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a LOT of energy and strength. xD

Comment: Glad to hear that @user4136548. However, make sure you tag your question next time with the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the returning address if you deleted it before, but you can easily control the memory from the outside, if you let it live before return.

For the second part, be careful about the const keyword, that indicates you can't modify the value inside the method.

Keep in mind that it's better to manage memory (creation and deletion) from the outside of method scope or in dedicated methods.